# I am not able to use XLS file in drools 6.3.0

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner, drools-fusion, drools-flow

I have created a XLSX file, And uploaded it, But am not able to see that xlsx converted decision table.

[image]

[image]

I have uploaded the xlsx file also. But not able to see the converted table.
Can anyone please suggest me what I am missing here.

Comment: Which option from the "New Item" menu are you using?

Comment: New Item -> DecisionTable (SpreadSheet)

Comment: @EstebanAliverti am I using a wrong option.?